# how to display address over each marker in google map

Tags: google-maps

My code is displaying markers on every output location but i want to display address over marker.I mean when user click the marker the address will have to appear above marker.How i can achieve this task? I have only latitude and longitude not address.

**test.php:**

```
 <?php


 $sql=<<<EOF
  SELECT * from markers;
 EOF;
 $result = $db->query($sql);
 $yourArray = array();
 $index = 0;

 while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){

 $json[] = array(
 'lat' => $row['latitude'],
 'lon' => $row['longitude'],
 'name' => $row['name']


   );

  }

$db->close();


 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
     #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 50%;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <h3></h3>
 <div id="map" align="left"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDj38Snh4MEIsomOlTZfARryo7V8A_qk9o&callback=initMap">
 </script>

 <?php json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 function initMap() {

 var locationsJSON = <?php echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;

  var locations = locationsJSON;

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.5546, 74.3572),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});




var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    console.log(locations[i]);


    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lon);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });
}


}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is the coordinates (latitude and longitude), your only option is to use the [reverse geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding):

(from that [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)):

> The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.

However (unless the code you posted is not the area you are planning on mapping) the area of your map doesn't seem to produce reliable reverse geocode results.  So I would suggest you populate the database with the address as well as the coordinates.

[fiddle using reverse geocoded results in the infowindow](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/r4mvLzbo/4/)

[image: screenshot]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {

  var locationsJSON = [
  {lat: 31.564614,lon: 74.298718}, 
  {lat: 31.563892,lon: 74.300435}, 
  {lat: 31.565546,lon: 74.297597}, 
  {lat: 31.565332,lon: 74.296744}, 
  {lat: 31.565332,lon: 74.296744}, 
  {lat: 31.565272,lon: 74.297637}, 
  {lat: 31.562347,lon: 74.296712}];

  var locations = locationsJSON;

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.5546, 74.3572),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lon);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
      var mark = this;
      geocoder.geocode({
        location: evt.latLng
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == "OK") {
          infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address + "<br>" + results[0].geometry.location.toUrlValue(6));
          infowindow.open(map, mark);
        }
      });
    });
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: hey can u tell me how to zoom to difefrenet city id's.for example in my json data i have city_id (1,2,3,4,5) and if city_id=1 i want to zoom map to 31.5546, 74.3572 this longitude and latitude and if city_id==2 i want to zoom it 25.2048, 55.2708 this how i can i do this?

Comment: That is another question.

Comment: i have posted but no one replied :( [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258999/how-to-zoom-map-according-to-city-id )